# How to Swap Chars like a byte-swap but with in a String with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, swap

I'm looking for the fastest way (computationally speaking) to do :

CDAB to ABCD

Say I have this list of strings:

a = ['3412','7895','0042','1122','0001']

And I want my output to be a string b = 12349578420022110100 with something like a 16-bit byte-swap

My code goes (I used the entry as a string but it will be a list soon):

```
a = '34127895004211220001'
b = ''
i = 0

while (i < len(a)):
    b = b + a[i + 2:i + 4] + a[i:i + 2]
    i = i + 4

print(b)
```

b = 12349578420022110100

Do you think this approach is the best one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Ashwini mentioned it's depend on input size.
But my approach is to add how many possible `functions` so my solution is this:

```
def swap(string):
    return string[-2:] + string[:-2]

a = ['3412','7895','0042','1122','0001']
s = ''.join(swap(a[i]) for i in range(len(a)))

print(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just two possibilities (which are both based on your code):

```
a = ['3412', '7895', '0042', '1122', '0001']

def first():
    return ''.join([ i[-2:]+i[:2] for i in a ])

def second():
    return ''.join(map(lambda i: i[-2:]+i[:2], a))

print(first())
print(second())

import timeit

print(timeit.timeit('first()', globals=globals()))  # 1.14
print(timeit.timeit('second()', globals=globals()))  # 1.34
```

If you have several millions of swaps to do, maybe I also would first try to check if the bottleneck is really the swapping. It also quite likely depends on the length of a (if much longer other methods e.g. numpy may be faster).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the input size, if your input size is small your current approach is fine. For bigger input, it's recommended to not use `+` to build large strings, as new memory needs to be allocated every time and lots of copying happens and results in quadratic runtime.

The recommended way is to build a list and join it using `str.join`:

```
>>> a = '34127895004211220001'
>>> "".join([a[i + 2:i + 4] + a[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(a), 4)])
'12349578420022110100'
```

Docs:

- https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations (Note 6)